# is there a function in opencv, that can detect the curves in following image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project, which needs to locate several curves in a image. 
Is there any build-in function in opencv, that can detect such curves?
The following picture shows, in the red circle the several curves need to be detected. That curves are later used for locating the contour.

[image]

Comment: It is possible to detect the features you want but I don't know a single function call that will do all the work. First, I would fix rotation, then enhance the 45 degree diagonal lines using morphological operations, then locate the segments. It more work than I'm willing to do as a volunteer so I will not post a solution but if you try it for yourself I can try to nudge you in the right direction. Perhaps there are other ways to address the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to locate the curves within a rectangle roughly. Size of rectangle can be estimated using the circle radius. For each rectangle I can use a template, which is derived from other image. Using template matching I may recive a good result.(I doubt it a little bit) At the end I need to locate the corresponding points in two images of the same object, which are taked in two different view points.

Comment: I don't have good experiences with template matching, for this image I would use something like Houghline and heuristics (look for segments of the same size in 90 degree angle relative to each other, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider about your idea.